# Java using method of the correct object

Tags: java, arrays

this might be something very obvious but i am really struggling with the problem, any help would be appreciated.

i am trying to make a program that has an `Activity` class, which is a superclass for `Run` `Swim` `Cycle` classes, and there is another class called member.

a member has an arraylist called diary which keeps records of the distances made by a member

```
 private ArrayList<Activity>diary = new ArrayList<>();
```

activities are added like so:

```
 public void addActivity(Activity a){
    diary.add(a);

 }
```

now i need to get the distances for each of the classes in to an array and display the correct distance covered in each type of activity, i tried doing this:

```
public double[] getTotalDistances(){
   double distance[];
   distance = new double[3];


    for (Activity r: diary){
           distance[0] += r.getDistance(); 
    }
    for(Activity c: diary ){
           distance[1] += c.getDistance(); 
    }

    for(Activity s: diary ){
           distance[2] += s.getDistance(); 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++){
        System.out.println(distance[i]);

    }




    return distance;
   }
```

but this returns the getDistance() method of only the superclass, if i do this:

```
for (Run r: diary){
           distance[0] += r.getDistance(); 
    }
```

then java complains that those are incompatible types :

```
incompatible types. required: run, found: activity.
```

if run is a subclass of activity then why would it complain about incompatibility?
and how do i get it to work with the correct method (the getDistance method that is in the "run" class)

THanks!

Comment: `diary` contain objects of type `Activity`, not `Run`.

Comment: _"but this returns the getDistance() method of only the superclass"_ No, it won't. It will return `getDistance` of whatever the object is actually an instance of. The type of the reference doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already typed your list `diary` as `ArrayList<Activity>`, which means it contains elements of type `Activity`. Then you're asking Java to iterate by assuming that the list contains `Run` items, which it doesn't. This is because the list can contain any subclass of `Activity` and it doesn't make sense to assume one. So you really can't do more than:

```
for(Activity activity : diary) {
   ...
}
```

Now in the following three loops:

```
for (Activity r: diary){
       distance[0] += r.getDistance(); 
}

for(Activity c: diary ){
       distance[1] += c.getDistance(); 
}

for(Activity s: diary ){
       distance[2] += s.getDistance(); 
}
```

You're doing the same calculation three times! All you've done is given different names to the `Activity` instances (`r`, `c`, and `s`) so there is no way you can figure out what kind of activity it is. You could do `instanceof` checks like so:

```
for (Activity activity : diary){
    if (activity instanceof Run) {
        distance[0] += activity.getDistance(); 
    } else if (activity instanceof Cycle) {
        distance[1] += activity.getDistance();
    } else if (activity instanceof Swim) {
        distance[2] += activity.getDistance();
    }
}
```

This would work, but isn't very elegant. Instead let the object tell you what type it is. Create an `enum` called `ActivityType` and have your abstract `Activity` class have a method called `getActivityType`:

```
public abstract class Activity {    
    ...
    ...

    public abstract ActivityType getActivityType();
}
```

Then each subclass would implement this method and return the proper type:

```
public class Run extends Activity {
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public ActivityType getActivityType() {
        return ActivityType.RUN;
    }
}
```

and so on.

Then in your loop, you just need to do this:

```
for (Activity activity : diary){
    if (activity.getActivityType() == ActivityType.RUN) {
        distance[0] += activity.getDistance(); 
    } else if (activity.getActivityType() == ActivityType.CYCLE) {
        distance[1] += activity.getDistance();
    } else if (activity.getActivityType() == ActivityType.SWIM) {
        distance[2] += activity.getDistance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do inheritance like this.  The runtime won't filter out all of the `run`s from the things that aren't `run`s in your `diary`

you should instead do something like the following with the `instanceof` operator

```
for (Activity r: diary){
    if(r instanceof Run){
        distance[0] += r.getDistance(); 
    }
}
```